# Add a Canvas Form Control in Drupal Custom Module

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, form-control

Im currently developing a module and I have this code in html:

```
<canvas id="cnv" name="cnv" width="500" height="100"></canvas>
```

I want it to add in my page using form controls but when I scan through [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7) , there's no canvas form control available. How to make it possible in Drupal? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geez, what have they dont to that page? It use to be easy to read.

Anyway, you can use the [markup type](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup), which is the default so no need for '#type'.
eg.

```
$form['mycanvas'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<canvas id="cnv" name="cnv" width="500" height="100"></canvas>',
);
```

Though I'm not sure what you are doing with the canvas and if that will affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a canvas using html_tag type. [https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21HtmlTag.php/class/HtmlTag/8.2.x.](http://Documentation)

Here is the code.

```
$form['mycanvas']=array(
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'canvas',
      '#attributes' => array(
                    'id'=> 'cnv',
                    'name'=>'cnv',
                    'style'=>'border: 1px solid #000000;
                              width: 500;
                              height: 100;'
                            ),
      );
```